# Swift, image from URL returns nil due to corrupted file type hiding as JPG

Tags: ios, swift, laravel, image, image-processing

I'm experiencing a large issue right now with XCode and just MacOS/iOS in general.

For background, the website application framework I'm using is laravel and the image editor I use to crop profile images is called image intervention, a quite popular extension for laravel.

To skip straight into it- I'm creating a basic companion application for my website, which, like pretty much all other websites, stores images on the server. This can be reached with the `www.mywebsite.com/storage/` base URL, with the addition of the file name on the end. There is a bit more to it, but none of that is the issue.

I've been using it many times already, as there are multiple folders for different image relationships. One folder, lets just call it `postimages` (so link is now `www.mywebsite.com/storage/postimages`), returns images with no issue, and I've been using it multiple times up to this point. The code I use in swift to return the different images is as follows (in my specific views)

```
func getPic(urlLink: String)-> Image? {
    let baseURL = "https://www.mywebsite.com/storage"
    let url = URL(string: baseURL + urlLink)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
    let image2 = Image(uiImage: (image ?? nil)!)
    return image2
}
```

So this might be badly written or whatnot, but that's definitely not the source of any issue, so approach it as you wish. Anyways, again, I've used this function in multiple views to retrieve multiple different images from different folders on the storage endpoint.

The issue just came up when trying to retrieve images from a different endpoint, specifically my `/profileimages` endpoint. Up until now, as I've stated, this function has never had an issue. Now, when I try to use it to get profile images, it crashes the app with the error

> "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

around the line where it is `let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)`.

Now this gave me much grief because the URL (when hovered) showed the
correct URL link, and when I entered them into the browser it returned
the image in question. So why is the image somehow returning `nil`? I
don't know.

To add to the mystery, I've been trying to work around the issue, by downloading the default profile image and just changing the function to return the default image if there was no data at the URL (even though there should be, 100% of the time).

When I tried to download the default profile picture, by using the `https://www.mywebsite.com/storage/profileimages/blank.jpg` link, I tried adding it to XCode as an asset and it had a big red exclamation point over it. Trying to open it with preview gave me the error "The file "blank.jpg" could not be opened. It may be damaged or use a file format the Preview doesn't recognize." This is surprising because on my Windows computer, trying to do the same thing has no issue at all.

My suspicion is that because I used the extension to crop and fit the profile images to a square size, somehow in that process of saving it, image intervention corrupted the file, and while Windows recognizes it as JPEG, Swift does not.

I ask any of those who are more experienced with image manipulation please help me understand this, obviously displaying user's profile pictures is vital to creation of a website mobile companion application, and right now I can't do anything besides basic text tabviews without this working as intended.

Comment: You are mixing up unrelated things here.

`Unexpectedly found` is definitely coming from `url!` or `data!` (you are force unwrapping properties that can be nil). So a better code is (since your function returns optional anyway) `guard let url = URL(string: baseURL + urlLink) else { return nil }` and `guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) else { return nil }`.

Comment: And whether a blank image is valid or not is hard to say without seeing it. It might be that what you see in windows explorer is a placeholder for invalid image, also can you open it in Mac's finder or not?

Comment: Ok well I tried to say that that's what it was coming from, I guess I misexplained it, but that's not the source of my issues anyway. I'll implement this fix to the function anyways, just to cover myself in case somehow someone has a null value for their profile picture. Thank you.

Comment: The blank image most definitely is a valid image on Windows, it opens the image as it's supposed to appear on windows, and it is not a windows placeholder image. Windows would also pop up with an error if the file type did not fit the format of the document. Trying to open the image (downloaded from the very same URL link as on the windows pc) on Mac returns a popup saying the file is damaged or Preview doesn't recognize it.

Comment: The files are also identical in size on both computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post my own answer as I've been able to solve the mystery. The first problem was the default image was, indeed, corrupted. I made a new one with GIMP and have been using that one instead. Why Windows could still open it and MacOS couldn't is beyond me, perhaps they have stricter guidelines for what constitutes a JPG file and therefore the file sneaks past Windows but not Mac, whatever the issue, obviously replacing the file solved my problem. The second issue was returning nil, which I found out was because I wasn't percent encoding the URL link. Some users post pictures with spaces in it, so I needed to add percent encoding in order for it to work (for some reason). Both of those solutions combined has removed the entire problem I was facing and I no longer have pictures returning nil.

Answer (score -1):

I am facing same issue but I found solution, The image is in webp format, which is specially designed by google for chrome. iOS wont support webp.